# How to return an error on an invalid api request, using ASP.Net Core 3, SPA app

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-spa

I am using a SPA (React) app in ASP.Net Core 3.

What is happening is any request will first go to the back end and allow .Net to try and route it, if no route is found, it returns `index.html` and assumes that the SPA can handle routing.

Most the time I am quite happy with this, but I want to know if there is a way of excluding any routers to `api/` in that.

I find it very annoying that index.html is returned (with a 200) on any made-up `api/MadeUp/Request`.
Can't I have it returning 500 on invalid api requests, but still allowing the SPA to manage any other requests (i.e. returning index.html)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can add a middleware between `UseEndpoint()` and `UseSpa()` and return a 404 (or 500 if you prefer) if request uri starts with `/api`

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "default",
        pattern: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
});

app.Use((context, next) =>
{
    if(context.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments(new PathString("api")))
    {
        context.Response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status404NotFound;
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    return next();
});

app.UseSpa(spa =>
{
    spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";

    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        spa.UseReactDevelopmentServer(npmScript: "start");
    }
});
```

Comment: So the basic idea is, 1. let Endpoints/MVC try use the URL. 2. If Endpoints hasn't used it, and it starts with /api, throw an error. 3. If we still get here, then SPA can have the URL. I like this, simple, I should have thought of it.